# Overloading the << operator for a Pair of <std::string, std::Set>

Tags: c++

I'm working on a lab for my CS class, and we have to make HashMaps of Pokemon, Pokemon moves, Pokemon effectivites, and Pokemon ineffectivites. The HashMaps of the effectivities, and ineffectivities are of type `Pair<Key, Value>` where `Key` is a `std::string` and `Value` is a `Set<std::string>`. When I'm trying to output the HashMap using my `toString()` function, I get the following:

```
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type '_Ty2' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   Lab 9   c:\users\maxos\onedrive\_dev\lab 9\lab 9\hashmap.h  100
```

I think it has something to do with not knowing how to use `<<` on the `Set<std::string>`, but I have the `<<` operator overloaded in the class. Any ideas? Thanks!

I've tried overloading the operator in the actual `Set` class, and also in the underlying `LinkedList` class but nothing has worked.

My `toString()` function:

```
virtual std::string toString() const
    {
        std::stringstream outputStream;
        outputStream << currSize << "/" << capacity << std::endl;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            if (myPairs[i].first.length())
            {
                outputStream << "  [" << i << ":" << 
        myPairs[i].first << "->" << myPairs[i].second << "]" << std::endl;

        }
    }
    return outputStream.str();
}
```

And my operator overload

```
friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const ModLinkedList<T>& list)
{
    os << list.toString();
    return os;
}
```

I just need the data to be properly outputted, but I'm not sure what I need to be overloading to fix this error.

Comment: What is `myPairs`?  Is `Pair` actually `std::pair`?  Is `Set` actually `std::set`?  This question needs more information, such as a [mcve], to be answerable.

Answer (score 0):

I've got quite a few downvotes, so sorry if my question was poorly asked this is my first one :P. I figured out my problem though, I was just being dumb and trying to pass a LinkedList object into the << overload instead of a Set object.